# Синхронизация времени между множеством устройств на Android (Без доступа к интернету)

Tags: java, android

Не могу никак придумать как синхронизовать два устройства по времени

В Windows встречал утилиты NTPD, есть ли что-то похожее на Android, или мб кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: если нет интернета то синхронизируетесь другими средствами. блютуз к примеру

Comment: но ntpd синхронизируется через сервер точного времени в интернете. если вам нужно именно такое решение, то вы и в андроид можете использовать один из этих серверов, просто делая запрос

Comment: @pavlofff насколько я понял NTPD это всего лишь протокол

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать метод `Location.getTime()`

Comment: Это ооооочень не точно будет) Тут желательно синхронизация до миллисекунд